# What circumstances will cause a postgres 'unlogged' table to lose data?

Tags: postgresql-performance, postgresql-14

For performance reasons I have created a Postgres UNLOGGED table. Everything works fine, performance is blisteringly fast. But very occasionally I lose all the data in it. According to the documentation -

> an unlogged table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown

I use the following query to tell when the database last booted

```
SELECT to_char(pg_postmaster_start_time(),'YYYY-Mon-dd HH24:mi:ss') as dbstart
```

The query suggests that database was up and running when the UNLOGGED table was truncated, in which case, why was it truncated?

My question is exactly what constitutes a 'crash' that might cause the table to be truncated, and wouldn't that crash result in a change to the start-time returned in the above query? If the database hasn't restarted then why has the data been lost?

I realise it's plausible that something in the application that uses the database might be deleting data or truncating the table, but since this issue has only arisen since I switched to an UNLOGGED table then my guess is that this ISN'T a problem with the application itself.

Comment: Did you check the Postgres log file?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - couldn't spot anything obvious in the log file